# JNI: converting unsigned int to jint

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, unsigned-integer

How do I convert an unsigned int to jint? Do I have to convert it at all, or can I just return it without any special treatment? This is basically my code right now, but I can't test it, as I haven't setup JNI locally.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_test_test(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jlong ptr)
{
    MyObject* m = (MyObject*) ptr; 
    unsigned int i = m->get(); 
    return i; 
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the general case, `jint` is equivalent to `int`, and so can hold about half the values of `unsigned int`. Conversion will work silently, but if a `jint` value is negative or if an `unsigned int` value is larger than the maximum value a `jint` can hold, the result will not be what you are expecting.

Comment: I am storing only small numbers, that will never exceed the limits of a jint, so it should be fine.

Comment: @Jonathan Once the value reaches half the capacity of an unsigned int, it will give a negative int due to how the types are implemented; small values are fine

Comment: Yes, I know how `int` works. I'm asking Pedro if his data includes negative numbers.

Answer (score 11):

`jint` is a typedef for `int32_t` so all the usual casting rules apply.

Answer (score 11):

Depending on your compiler settings, there may or may not be a warning about mixing signed/unsigned integers. There will be no error. All the caveats from the answers above apply - `unsigned int` values of 0x80000000 (2,147,483,648) and above will end up as negative integers on the Java side.

If it's imperative that those large numbers are preserved in Java, use a `jlong` as a return datatype instead, and convert like this:

```
return (jlong)(unsigned long long)i;
```

The point is to first expand to 64 bits, then to cast away unsigned-ness. Doing it the other way around would produce a 64-bit negative number.